# How to restore Gmail inbox view?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

My Gmail inbox label is not appearing normal as shown in the attached photo
How can I restore labels to normal/default?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to click on those 3 lines to trigger different view mode:

[image: 0]